# How to create overlay plots from 20 CSV files in Python 2?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot, overlay

I generate 20 CSV files per each long calculation I do in python 2. From all data sets in each file, there are 2 set that are important here. First set, as row[0] on x-axis, and the third set as row[2] on y-axis. First set, (row[0]) is always the same, so one entry should suffice, but the third set (row[2]) changes by the file and needs to be plotted against (row[0]) as I need to plot all the third sets from all files superimposed.

I am not a programmer but I can plot them individually as per:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('energy.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(row[0])
        y.append(row[2])

plt.plot(x,y, label='Energies')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Energy Graph\n per particle')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('energy.png')
plt.savefig('energy.pdf')

plt.show()
```

But to superimpose all data sets I wanted to try "for file_name in files:" to append the data set to the filename as the variable and the plot them all at the end in one graph:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file_name in files:
            if file_name.endswith('.csv'):
                    print(file_name)
                    with open(file_name,'r') as csvfile:
                            plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
                            for row in plots:
                                    x.append(row[0])
                                    file_name.append(row[2])
            plt.plot(x,file_name, label='Loaded from file!')
            plt.xlabel('x')
            plt.ylabel('y')
            plt.title('Energy')
            plt.legend()
            plt.savefig('1.png')
            plt.savefig('1.pdf')

            plt.show()
```

Then I get this error:

> file_name.append(row[1])
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with `x.append` and `filename.append` ?

Comment: I guess x.append appends the data set I have in row[0]? which works coz I get the plot. I wish I could get every third row[] from each file by appending the set to the filename as a variable and then plot all the 20 sets from the thrid row of every file, on top of each other. I am not a programmer, so I can't comment on how it exactly works but if there is any other suggestion, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To create overlay plots, call `plt.plot()` iteratively.

```py
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file_name in files:
        if file_name.endswith('.csv'):
            print(file_name)
            x = []
            y = []
            with open(file_name,'r') as csvfile:
                plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
                for row in plots:
                    x.append(row[0])
                    y.append(row[2])
            plt.plot(x,y, label=file_name)

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Energy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Example:
`a.csv`

```
1,3,4,3,5
3,2,5,2,5
```

`b.csv`

```
1,3,2,3,5
3,2,6,2,5
```

then you'll get this plot:

[image: plot example]

But if the CSV files consist of numeric data, I recommend using NumPy because it is fast. :

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file_name in files:
        if file_name.endswith('.csv'):
            print(file_name)
            data = np.loadtxt(file_name, delimiter=',').transpose()
            plt.plot(data[0], data[2], label=file_name)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Energy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, this handles the data horizontally and if I provide horizontal data:  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

32,65,4,21,854,5,1423,25
5,4,32,132,1568,48,798,452
1,213,15,4,364,654,64,84
56,465,45,65,46,46,5456,4        gives this error after reading first file:     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: missing comma between 452 and 1?

Comment: It is a 4 row x 8 column, data set, the comment section didn't let me edit it.

Comment: Does the file have headers, blanks, or other non-numeric data? You can use `np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',')` to ignore non-numeric data.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this, it has but for the sake of getting this to work, I am using a simple set of data. How about I take this third set y.append.(row[0]) from every file (along with the file_name to be used as the label at the end) and write them to a new csv file and then plot all the data sets from final file new_y.append() along with the labels to plot the graphs?